# How does Spring apply the "lite" bean approach through a "plain old class"?

Tags: spring

About `Spring Framework` in the [Basic Concepts: @Bean and @Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) section exists the following `Full @Configuration vs “lite” @Bean mode?` block with the following first paragraph:

```
When @Bean methods are declared within classes that are not annotated with @Configuration, 
they are referred to as being processed in a “lite” mode. Bean methods declared in a @Component or
even in a plain old class are considered to be “lite”, with a different primary purpose of the 
containing class and a @Bean method being a sort of bonus there. For example, service components may 
expose management views to the container through an additional @Bean method on each applicable 
component class. In such scenarios, @Bean methods are a general-purpose factory method mechanism.
```

The `full` approach is:

```
@Configuration
class XConfig {

   @Bean
   X defineX(){
      ...
      return x;
   }

}
```

It is the classic and most known approach. About the `lite` approach, first its introduction:

##### Introduction

```
When @Bean methods are declared within classes that are not annotated with @Configuration
```

And according with the big block shown above exists two ways

##### One

```
Bean methods declared in a @Component
```

Therefore

```
@Component/@Service
class XSomething {

   ...

   @Bean
   X defineX(){
      ...
      return x;
   }

}
```

Until here the `XSomething` class can be detected and managed by Spring thanks to the combination of `@ComponentScan` together with `@Component/@Service`, **therefore** `@Bean` can be used by Spring too.

##### Two

```
or even in a plain old class
```

Here I am assuming the following:

```
//No annotation
class XSomething {

   ...

   @Bean
   X defineX(){
      ...
      return x;
   }

}
```

**Question**

- How does Spring apply here the "lite" bean approach through a **"plain old class"**?

If the `@Bean` is totally isolated or is not declared with neither `@Configuration` nor `@Component`. So How `@Bean` can be used by Spring?

Please clarify **two** because is not clear in the current documentation - there is neither a snippet nor sample code about this approach, perhaps I misinterpreted the `or even in a plain old class` part.

Comment: For anyone here trying to help, please note that the OP cross-posted in the issue tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29957